# ESLint - Way to recognize external (CDN) libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, eslint

Is there way to ESLint recognize externally imported js libraries from CDN?
Example:

index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/.../socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
const socket = io(); // Getting underline: ESLint: 'io' is not defined. (no-undef)
```

Is there some automatic way of making eslint recognize those or I need to add them as so: `/* globals io */`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I have found in the [eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-undef) is to add `/* global io */` to the top of your file.